# Order by letters and numbers

Tags: r

I have a `DF$vector` which looks like this:

```
A10 A50
C1 C4
B1
A7
C3
B1 B4
```

I look for a way to order it as follows:

```
A10 A50
A7
B1 B4
B1
C1 C4
C3
```

I tried to use `gsub` :

```
vector[order(gsub("([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)", "\\1", vector), 
             as.numeric(gsub("([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)", "\\2", vector)))]
```

But it didnt return what i want. 
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: @RonakShah i checked it as well. It didnt return exactly the order im looking for

Comment: works for me `d[mixedorder(d$V1),]`

Comment: @Jimbou That was my earlier option, but as the OP mentioned, the 2nd row should have B4 in second column

Answer (score 1):

We can use `order` from `base R`

```
df1[order(sub("\\d+", "", df1[,1]), as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", df1[,1])), df1[,2] == ""),]
#  A10 A50
#3  A7    
#5  B1  B4
#2  B1    
#1  C1  C4
#4  C3
```

#### data

```
df1 <-structure(list(A10 = c("C1", "B1", "A7", "C3", "B1"), A50 = c("C4", 
 "", "", "", "B4")), .Names = c("A10", "A50"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: thanks! but what if a `vector` would contain `B1` instead of `B3`, then `mixedorder` would place it before `B1 B4`, is a way to overcome it? Thank you!

Comment: @Pooh Please tell us whether you have a data.frame or vector.  It doesn't look like a vector

Comment: Well i have a data.frame but im looking to order only one column

Comment: @Pooh Well, then, please clarfiy it in your post `I have a vector which looks like this` is confusing:

Answer (score 0):

In programming languages, the letters are considered to be increasing in terms of magnitude. Thus `A` is considered to be **less**than `B`etc. Thus to order the above, just use the code:

```
     df1$r=rank(df1$A10,ties.method = "last")
     df1[order(df1$r),-ncol(df1)]
      A10 A50
   3  A7    
   5  B1  B4
   2  B1    
   1  C1  C4
   4  C3
```

Comment: as you may not noticed I was looking for ordering `B1` after `B1 B4` and not before

Comment: Wow I never saw that.. Should that just happen to B1 or even if there was a C1, then it should be after C1 and C4??

Comment: its not only for `B1` but for any case, so that for `C1` as well

Comment: so the result I gave did not meet your expectation? I think I do not quite understand you we'll. Check my result again please. I did edit it

Comment: the problem is that `DF$vector` is a character vector of a dataframe and not 2 columns as you assumed